# I leak memory only when using h264_cuvid, ffmpeg, libav c

Tags: c, ffmpeg, memory-leaks, valgrind, nvidia

```c
typedef struct file
{
    AVFormatContext *container;
    AVCodecContext **codec;
} file;

int decode_frame(file *decoder, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *packet);
int open_media(file *video, const char input_path[], const char *video_codec, const char *audio_codec);
int free_file(file *f);

int main()
{
    file *input1 = malloc(sizeof(file));

    int res;

    res = open_media(input1, "https://clips-media-assets2.twitch.tv/AT-cm%7C1257727679.mp4", "h264_cuvid", "copy");

    if (res != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed opening input 1");
        return 1;
    }

    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    
    AVPacket *packet = av_packet_alloc();

    if (!frame || !packet)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        res = decode_frame(input1, frame, packet);

        if (res == 1)
        {
            printf("error decoding frame\n");
            return 1;
        }

        if (res == -1)
        {
            printf("File ended\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    av_frame_free(&frame);

    av_packet_free(&packet);

    free_file(input1);
}
```

I get this valgrind output when using h264_cuvid

==41881== LEAK SUMMARY:

==41881==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==41881==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==41881==      possibly lost: 2,576 bytes in 17 blocks

==41881==    still reachable: 1,043,267 bytes in 102 blocks

==41881==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==41881== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.

==41881== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all

==41881==

==41881== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from

==41881== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s

==41881== ERROR SUMMARY: 1923 errors from 26 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

but if I use copy or h264 I get this

==42263==

==42263== HEAP SUMMARY:

==42263==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

==42263==   total heap usage: 108,504 allocs, 108,504 frees, 65,148,048 bytes allocated

==42263==

==42263== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

==42263==

==42263== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s

==42263== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Do I have to free some extra stuff when using h264_cuvid?

```c
int free_file(file *f)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < f->container->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        avcodec_free_context(&f->codec[i]);
    }

    av_free(f->codec);

    avformat_close_input(&f->container);

    av_free(f);
}
```

This function frees the files

```c
int open_media(file *video, const char input_path[], const char *video_codec, const char *audio_codec)
{
    video->container = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (!video->container)
    {
        printf("Failed to alloc memory to the container of the input file");
        return 1;
    }
    if (avformat_open_input(&video->container, input_path, NULL, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to open input file");
        return 1;
    }
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(video->container, NULL) < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to open read stream info");
        return 1;
    }

    video->codec = av_mallocz_array(video->container->nb_streams, sizeof(*video->codec));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < video->container->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        const char *curr_codec;

        AVStream *stream = video->container->streams[i];
        const AVCodec *dec;
        AVCodecContext *codec_ctx;

        if (AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO == stream->codecpar->codec_type)
        {
            curr_codec = video_codec;
        }
        else if (AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO == stream->codecpar->codec_type)
        {
            curr_codec = audio_codec;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(curr_codec, "copy") == 0)
            dec = avcodec_find_decoder(stream->codecpar->codec_id);

        else
            dec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name(video_codec);

        if (!dec)
        {
            printf("failed to find the codec");
            return 1;
        }

        codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
        if (!codec_ctx)
        {
            printf("failed to alloc memory for codec context");
            return 1;
        }

        if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar) < 0)
        {
            printf("failed to fill codec context");
            return 1;
        }

        if (avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, dec, NULL) < 0)
        {
            printf("failed to open codec");
            return 1;
        }

        video->codec[i] = codec_ctx;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function prepares the AVCodecContext and AVFormatContext for decoding the input file
and takes as input the audio decoder and video decoder

```c
/*
    returns:
    1 if error
    0 if success
    -1 if file ended
*/
int decode_frame(file *decoder, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *packet)
{
    AVCodecContext *dec;

    while (true)
    {
        av_packet_unref(packet);
        if (av_read_frame(decoder->container, packet) < 0)
            break;

        int index = packet->stream_index;

        dec = decoder->codec[index];

        int response = avcodec_send_packet(dec, packet);

        if (response < 0)
        {
            printf("Error while sending packet to decoder");
            return 1;
        }

        while (response >= 0)
        {
            response = avcodec_receive_frame(dec, frame);
            if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (response < 0)
            {
                printf("Error while receiving frame from decoder");
                return 1;
            }
            if (response >= 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            av_frame_unref(frame);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

this function decodes frames from the video

Comment: What's  the output when you run it with `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` ?

Comment: You forgot to call `avformat_free_context(f->container);` after `avformat_close_input(&f->container);`. I don't think this is the cause for the memory leak. I can't use valgrind under Windows for testing it.

Comment: @aergistal https://pastebin.com/08ABLNBm pastebin of the output, I used this command "valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./out 2> error.txt 1> output.txt"

Comment: May be related I think I may have problems with the nvidia drivers, it used to output frames correctly, now it outputs [AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x55dc29080400] cu->cuInit(0) failed -> CUDA_ERROR_COMPAT_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_DEVICE: forward compatibility was attempted on non supported HW, I use a 1060 ti, I am sure it does have h264_cuvid